# El carrousel (slider) de react-slick no me funciona

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, slider, slick-carousel

tengo un problema, que al querer hacer un build, me da el siguiente error

```
Type error: 'Slider' cannot be used as a JSX component.
```

Its instance type 'Slider' is not a valid JSX element.
The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
Type 'import("C:/Users/lucas/Desktop/ghimprove/Proyectos/newghi/ghinext/ghimprove-home/node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/ts5.0/index").ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'React.ReactNode'.
Type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor>' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
Property 'children' is missing in type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor>' but required in type 'ReactPortal'.

174 |           
175 |

> 176 |               <Slider {...settings}>
> |                ^
> 177 |                 
> 178 |                   
> 179 |

Alguien sabe qué puede ser? A alguien le pasó?

Answer (score 0):

El problema parece ser que estás tratando de renderizar un componente Slider, pero el método **render()** de este componente no está devolviendo un JSX válido.

Para resolver este error, deberías revisar la implementación del componente Slider y asegurarte de que su método **render()** devuelva un JSX válido.

Comment: Perfecto!! Ya lo pude solucionar, era una actualización de las librerías. Muchas gracias!! :D